# Comment utilise-t-on des guillemets ?

Tags: ponctuation

Je suis désolé si cette question est basique. Mais, j'ai besoin d'aide à propos de l'emplacement des guillemets.
En particulier, doit-on écrire :

> Appelez la « [norme d'opérateur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norme_d'op%C3%A9rateur) ».

ou

> Appelez « la norme d'opérateur ».

Une autre exemple :

> Il est « l'[espace de Hilbert](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_de_Hilbert) ».

ou

> Il est l'« espace de Hilbert ».

Comment: Les exemples que tu donnes ne sont pas très bien choisis, ils ne correspondent pas à ta véritable question. Le premier *la* n'est pas un article mais un pronom dans le premier exemple. Dans le second l'usage des guillemets est douteux.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je voulais que mes exemples soient simples ; ils n'aparaissent pas dans un ouvrage réelle de mathématiques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien que les guillemets ne soient pas ici d'un emploi usuel, on peut essayer de les mettre en perspective :

> Sinon pour cette norme :
>
> - dites : « la norme d'opérateur » lorsque vous voulez utilisez les contraintes de cette norme.
> - ou appelez-la « norme d'opérateur » pour définir un type de norme.

De même :

> Cet « Espace de Hilbert » est définit dans ce document.
>
> Il est « l'espace de Hilbert » dont on vient de parler.

---

Dans votre exemple : *Appelez « la norme d'opérateur »* est à l'impératif, on s'attend à ce qu'elle accoure comme un chien que l'on siffle, alors que l'exemple précédent est correct ; il eut fallu écrire *Appel**ée** « la norme d'opérateur »*

Pour l'espace de Hilbert, ne pas utiliser *Il est* sauf peut-être dans une présentation orale, mais plutôt *C'est « l'espace de Hilbert »*.

Dans les articles, on met plutôt ce genre de nom en italique, ou parfois, dans les documents techniques en casse fixe du genre `courrier new`.

Comment: Ça veut dire que, en résumé, les articles « le » et « la » soient toujours inclus dans des guillemets avec le nom, pour spécifiquement des termes mathématiques ? (Et oui, je suis courant d'utiliser les termes mathématiques en italiques. Toutefois, mon livre mathématique utilise plutôt les guillemets pour une terme particulaire.)

Comment: Mettre des guillemets, c'est habituellement rapporter une parole, de ce fait, l'article est inclus - N.B. : ... *pour un terme particulier*, s'il s'agit d'un terme original, *pour un terme particulaire*, s'il s'agit d'un terme technique concernant les particules (à réserver aux ouvrages techniques). :)

Answer (score 2):

Les guillemets jouent [*essentiellement*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3363) deux rôles; le **premier**, fondamental, consiste à indiquer le *discours rapporté* (citation et discours direct); le **deuxième**, autre, consiste à *mettre en valeur* ou à *éloigner* un terme du discours.

*Le bon usage*, au §134, traite généralement des cas des *mots étrangers*, *régionalismes*, *néologismes* et *mots familiers/populaires* que les guillemets peuvent servir à encadrer. En ce qui a trait à l'*éloignement*, dans la *BDL* on identifie notamment l'utilisation avec des termes : « *familiers, populaires ou vulgaires, de jargon, de tournures maladroites ou fautives, d’expressions employées de manière ironique, de mots rares ou insolites, d’écarts orthographiques ou grammaticaux, etc.* » (*BDL*) Dans ce contexte, [on indique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3391) que les guillemets n'**encadrent que le mot ou l'expression** (il n'y a pas d'expression en question) et non le déterminant qui l'accompagne. « *Je suis descendue du haut en bas de la colline en empruntant les « traboules ».* » (Beauvoir, *Tout compte fait*). On assimile l'emploi des guillemets avec un terme technique dans un texte non technique à la *mise en valeur*; il n'y a aucune indication à la *BDL* qu'on encadrerait davantage un déterminant dans ce cas (« *Ils obtiennent une image médicale au moyen d’un « dispositif de balayage ».* »).

Dans la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14127) on indique comment on pourrait au final encadrer ce qu'on pourrait désigner soit comme du discours direct (impératif : dites + qqc. entre guillemets) soit comme une forme d'*autonymie* ( « *Ça* n'est pas ancien »; marqué ici par l'italique sur le ça). Ça n'a aucun impact sur ce qui précède dans le contexte de la question à mon avis; l'enseignement des sciences ne constitue pas un exercice où l'on dirait à l'étudiant exactement le morceau de phrase requis, avec son article, pour parler d'un concept. À titre d'illustration, dans les deux articles *Wikipédia* présentés en question, le caractère gras, utilisé assurément pour mettre en évidence le terme en paragraphe introductif, est employé sur les termes justement, et non sur les déterminants.

Enfin, on veut possiblement dire « *on l'appelle* » et « *il s'agit de* », respectivement, dans les exemples proposés; il s'agit d'une difficulté beaucoup plus importante que celle des guillemets, me semble-t-il.

Comment: Vous trouverez http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/gallerie-guillemet.html , en bas de page, le bon usage des guillemets vu par un typographe. P.S. : Et pourquoi pas le second plutôt que le deuxième ?