# Why doesn't dialogue use any identifying punctuation in French?

Tags: ponctuation, comparaison-de-langues, littérature, dialogues

Reading books in French, I've noticed that the formatting of dialogue differs from English in a slightly confusing way. See this example:

> — N'importe quoi ! répondit François en riant. Les monstres ne vivent pas dans les forêts, ils vivent juste dans notre imagination.

In English this would be written approximately:

> “Don't be ridiculous!” replied François, laughing. “Monsters don't live in forests, they live in our imagination.”

Note that in the English version there are quotes around the bits where the character is speaking. It's not exactly *difficult* to read it the French way, but I feel it is a little less clear and seems like an odd formatting choice. Is it assumed that when the narrator is speaking again rather than the character, it will always be preceded by a line break?

What if it's switching between the voice of the character and that of the narrator, e.g.:

> “I didn't want to go,” she said. “But the truth is I knew I would regret it if I didn't.” She paused, idly turning over the picture in her hand. “It was the right choice.”

Without the quotes, that would be a bit annoying to read! Especially since in certain authorial styles, paragraphs like that can become quite drawn out!

When did French evolve this style, and is it universal? Was there ever previously a different method which eventually fell out of favor?

Comment: I don't think you can find a logic (does it have to ?). I also find it confusing in french. I think the autor has to be clear, make a new line if necessary, or change the sentence...

Comment: Sometimes I like to ask questions I don't really *need* to know the answer to. It's a personality defect.

Comment: Your example is not a dialogue but a simple quotation one person speaking. To have a dialogue you need at least two people exchanging. And French dialogue uses quotes as well.

Comment: Aaaaannnnd Laure with the technicalities. Fine. MONOLOGUES.

Comment: Quotation marks should be used with monologues as well. Some people just don't respect the rules, chiefly on the web. A good publisher will /should.

Comment: Related: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13341/in-dialogue-how-do-we-separate-the-speakers-from-the-narrators-voice/13346#13346

Comment: Merci!  +1 de retour!  **;-)**

Comment: Incidentally (and not having read all of the below in detail, but possibly with some overlap with de la Dauversière), recall that readers used to get by without any quotation marks whatsoever. I had an ancient copy of some translation of the Arabian Nights with none at all at the age of 10, and while it was sometimes deeply confusing, it really stretched the mind to figure out what was narrative commentary and what was spoken in the middle multi-paragraph diatribes. ;)

Comment: I never found it difficult at all. A friend of mine, a Spaniard, often complained to me that the single "!" in French and English alike was confusing to him, since he had to "guess" what was exclamed. He seemed to find the "bracketty" Spanish system (¡ exclamation !) much clearer and more flexible. I feel this is one analogous non-issue, which practice should soon dissolve without you having to pay too much attention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm an historian of neither French nor English typography, but having read quite a bit of French and English literature and knowing a bit about typography in multiple languages, I can tell you that French *doesn't need the quotes like English does, as it's obvious from the **tenses** where one person's conversation begins and ends*.

The use of the Passé Simple and Présent from your quote is a prime example of this! As typography evolved with technology, French typography just took a different path on its evolutionary ladder than English did.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez or both ... I might be wrong but It seems Fabby is implying using french guillemets and accented uppercase characters wasn't the rule in the past and is just something recent due to the spread of word processing. I would say on the opposite that their usage was the rule for centuries but only temporarily dropped as a side effect of the typewriters limitations.

Comment: Typewriter example removed as it seems to deter from the main message: it was just an example of evolution of "typography" due to technical limitations. Same goes for handwriting, wooden printing press, letter setting, ...

Answer (score 6):

French should use quotation marks when reporting direct speech.
Your example should be written :

> « N'importe quoi ! répondit François en riant. Les monstres ne vivent pas dans les forêts, ils vivent juste dans notre imagination. »

Note the use of double angle quotes with non-breaking spaces.

When reporting a dialogue (ie two or more people exchanging spoken words) quotation marks should be placed at the beginning and at the end of the dialogue;  to show the change of person you have a line break and start the line with a hyphen.

Example from *le lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie Nationale*:

> « Ma vue s'affaiblit dit Irène.
>   — Prenez des lunettes, dit Esculape
>   — Je m'affaiblis moi-même, continue-t-elle, et je ne suis ni si forte ni si saine que j'ai été.
>   — C'est, dit le dieu, que vous vieillissez.
>   — Mais quel moyen de guérir de cette langueur ?
>   — Le plus court, Irène, c'est de mourir comme ont fait votre mère et votre aïeule. » (La Bruyère, *Caractères*.)

You can read [that page](http://www.la-ponctuation.com/guillemets.html) as well.

Comment: You're just formalizing the rules sketched in the question. But the question asked why and how these rules originated.

Comment: @Gilles Agreed I am not answering about the origin of the rules,  but the point was to tell OP he was making the wrong assumption about those rules. Should have been a comment but could not fit it in a comment.

Comment: What wrong assumption? It's not that uncommon to present dialogue without quotation marks, with just a leading dash on each line of dialogue. Or monologue for that matter.

Comment: (While I of course haven't read as much French as any native speakers here, I second Gilles's assertion-- in what I *have* read, I see that formatting style fairly often.)

Comment: @Gilles French punctuation rules says there should be (cf my answer) and, but writers and publishers sometimes have their own style. Just as some publishers use the inverted commas English style in place of the double angle quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Sans connaître le contexte typographique dans lequel s'insère l'extrait, il est difficile de juger du choix de convention typographique qu'on a fait, et de la cohérence de son application dans l’œuvre. La question s'articule différemment selon qu'on l'envisage sous l'angle des guillemets en citation ou dans un dialogue, du tiret, ou de l'incise et du type de discours. Voici un complément aux autres réponses.

---

On a des guillemets *principalement* en début/fin de citation et avec le discours direct ; *parfois* avec le [discours indirect libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discours_indirect_libre) ; et *plus rarement* avec le discours indirect lié ; même sur une partie uniquement du discours indirect ; avec le *dialogue*, le plus clair consiste à utiliser les guillemets ouvrants en première réplique, et les fermants à la fin de la dernière (avec nuances en ce qui a trait à ce qui se passe entre les deux) ; ou on se passe carrément de guillemets et on utilise que des tirets ; enfin on renonce *ordinairement* à isoler hors guillemets une *brève incise* comme *dit-il* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goose, 14e, ed. Duculot au §134 ; voir aussi [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14130) et [cela](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14167)). À la *BDL* on dit [*rarement*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3375) les guillemets avec le discours indirect en général ; puis on aborde l'incise en citation selon qu'elle soit longue ou courte et son impact sur l'emploi des guillemets :

> Lorsqu’une brève incise coupe la citation, on inclut cette incise dans les guillemets, bien qu’elle ne fasse pas partie de la citation comme telle; si elle est longue, on ferme les guillemets avant l’incise pour les rouvrir après, afin de délimiter clairement ce qui appartient vraiment à la citation.
> [...]
>
> - « Vous saisissez? **demanda-t-il**. Alors, je continue mon raisonnement. » (incise courte)
> - « Nos résultats indiquent une concentration de BPC anormalement élevée », **concluent les experts au terme d’une étude troublante**, « et exigent de ce fait une intervention immédiate. » (incise longue : fermeture et réouverture des guillemets)
>
> ---
>
> Lorsqu'on emploie le tiret pour marquer les changements de locuteur, on peut faire précéder la première réplique du dialogue d'un guillemet ouvrant plutôt que d'un tiret. Dans ce cas, on doit faire suivre la dernière réplique du dialogue d'un guillemet fermant. Cette pratique est aujourd'hui facultative et l'on peut se contenter de faire précéder chaque réplique d'un tiret, sans employer les guillemets.
>
> ---
>
> [ Banque de dépannage linguistique, BDL (n.b. QC), [*guillemets et citation*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3375), et [*tiret dans les dialogues*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3371) ; voir [aussi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3327) ]

[Ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16793) on a fait état des règles en usage à l'*Imprimerie Nationale* (voir aussi *Orthotypographie.fr* à [dialogue](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/date-dynastie.html#Dialogue), [citation](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/cabochon-citation.html#Citation)) ; puis dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16795) on a noté avec grande justesse la différence des temps des verbes du discours de ceux de la narration, contribuant à [isoler](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13341) l'incise. Le « chemin de jardin » est bien « éclairé » (mon avis). On peut essayer de comparer avec certains cas moins usuels en anglais ([*indirect + medial parentheticals*](https://archive.org/stream/TheCambridgeGrammarOfTheEnglishLanguage/The%20Cambridge%20grammar%20of%20the%20English%20language#page/n1037/mode/2up) ; [généralement](https://archive.org/stream/TheCambridgeGrammarOfTheEnglishLanguage/The%20Cambridge%20grammar%20of%20the%20English%20language#page/n1765/mode/2up)). Avec l'emploi le plus [usuel](https://archive.org/stream/TheCambridgeGrammarOfTheEnglishLanguage/The%20Cambridge%20grammar%20of%20the%20English%20language#page/n1039/mode/2up) en anglais on n'hésite pas, semble-t-il (je ne prends pas position ; on notera qu'il s'agit de la *CGEL* de 2002), à isoler la brève incise.

---

Enfin, on se rappellera que les [*guillemets*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/guillemet) apparaissent au 16e (1527, cf. [1](https://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&id=5eUcAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22Structure%20de%20l%27orthographe%20fran%C3%A7aise%22%20%20catach&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=guillemets), [2](https://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&id=ZIfhAAAAMAAJ&dq=nina%20catach%20la%20ponctuation&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=1527)) alors que le mot comme tel ne fait son apparition qu'en 1677. On a traité de l'origine des guillemets dans un [article](http://www.lexpress.fr/culture/deux-points-et-guillemets-le-proces-verbal_779087.html) où on fait le parallèle avec le [*diplè*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet#Histoire) (chevron, en grec). On note par exemple que c'était initialement utilisé uniquement en marge de texte chez les [*scoliastes*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholie) et que « [j]usqu'au XIXe siècle au moins, les guillemets ne servent qu'à la citation au sens strict » (*Deux-points et guillemets : le " procès-verbal "*, ds. *L'Express*). L'absence du mot au lexique n'a pas empêché d'en discuter, par exemple au chapitre des parenthèses dans une grammaire ancienne :

[image: Citation sur les parenthèses, tirée de « La maniere de bien traduire d'une langue en autre d'advantage de la punctuation de la langue francoyse, plus des accents d'ycelle" à propos des parenthèses ».]

Transcription:

> Sans aulcune vigueur de Parenthese on trouue quelquesfois vu demy cercle en ceste sorte ) ou ainsi ], et cela se faict quand nous exposons quelque mot, ou quant nous glosons quelque sentence d’aulcun autheur Grec, Latin, Francoys ou de toute autre langue.
>
> On trouue aussi ces demys cercles aucunesfois doublés : et ce sans force de Parenthese. Ils se doublent doncq’ ainsi [ ] ou 6 9. Et lors en iceulx est comprinse quelque addition, ou exposition notée sur la matiere, que traicte l’autheur par nous interpreté. Mais le tout ( comme i’ay dict ) se faict sans efficace de Parenthese. Lisant les bons autheurs, et bien imprimés, tu pourras congnoistre ma traditiue estre vraye.

<sup>[*La maniere de bien traduire d'une langue en autre d'advantage de la punctuation de la langue francoyse, plus des accents d'ycelle*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OOQ-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22Sans%20aulcune%20vigueur%20de%20Parenthese%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Sans%20aulcune%20vigueur%20de%20Parenthese%22&f=false), Estienne Dolet, Paris, 1540</sup>

---

Il semble inexact d'affirmer qu'en français la ponctuation (les guillemets ici) est absente en dialogue ou en citation pour isoler le propos de sa narration. Dans les cas où les guillemets sont absents, cette absence n'est pas déterminante. La comparaison est intéressante, mais la difficulté qu'on présente en langue anglaise ne se transpose pas directement ici. Un usage existe où la brève incise (facilement reconnaissable vu l'inversion fréquente du pronom, l'encadrement par la virgule et le temps du verbe différent de celui du discours) peut apparaître à l'intérieur de guillemets le rapportant. Dans un dialogue où l'on s'est passé de guillemets, on ne les réintroduira pas pour délimiter l'incise, brève ou non. La combinaison du tiret et d'autres choix typographiques concurrents comme l'*italique* peut donner toutes sortes de résultats ; il faut regarder le paragraphe, la page et l’œuvre. Plus qu'une règle en particulier, on vise la cohérence et, surtout, la clarté de l'ensemble, tel l'exemple suivant, limpide malgré deux usages distincts :

> Comme nous évoquions les multiples affaires que le Gouvernement britannique avait traitées avec moi : « Savez-vous, me dit M. Eden avec bonne humeur, que vous nous avez causé plus de difficultés que tous nos alliés d'Europe ? » — « Je n'en doute pas », répondis-je, en souriant, moi aussi. « La France est une grande puissance. »
>
> [ De Gaulle, *Mémoires de guerre*, présenté au *LBU* au §135 ]

Answer (score 0):

In English the quotes separate the spoken parts from the non spoken parts.
In French the quotes (*guillemets français*) are used to separate the entire dialogue from the narration, including the non spoken parts of the dialogue, and there's only one pair of quotes per dialogue.

> Quand ils arrivèrent dans la forêt, Monty s'inquiéta :
>
> « Tu crois qu'il y a des monstres ici ?
>
> — N'importe quoi ! répondit François en riant. Les monstres ne
> vivent pas dans les forêts, ils vivent juste dans  notre
> imagination. »

Some publishers do not use quotes for dialogue, mainly for convenience' sake, because it's easier to use the em dash (*tiret cadratin*) to start the dialogue without having to "close" it.

Comment: You're just formalizing the rules sketched in the question. But the question asked why and how these rules originated.

Answer (score -1):

My answer won't discuss the various ways to render a dialogue in French or provide any clue as to their origin so it's more of a glorified comment than anything else but your assumption/observation does not seem entirely accurate.

Case in point, here are a few excerpts from Camus's *La Peste*, in the 1962 Pléiade edition:

> « C'est bien, dit-il, très bien. »
>
> Un moment après, à la gare, il l'installait dans le wagon-lit. Elle regardait le compartiment.
>
> « C'est trop cher pour nous, n'est-ce pas ?
>
> – Il le faut, dit Rieux.
>
> – Qu'est-ce que c'est que cette histoire de rats ?
>
> – Je ne sais, c'est bizarre, mais cela passera. »

---

> « Il y a un télégramme pour vous, là-haut », dit M. Michel.

---

> « Les mesures sont insuffisantes.
>
> […]
>
> – Je vais demander des ordres au Gouvernement général. »
>
> Rieux raccrocha devant Castel :
>
> « Des ordres ! Et il faudrait de l'imagination.
>
> […]

So quotation marks can be and are used in various ways. Even line breaks do not preclude opening and closing quotes as appropriate. Only short incident clauses (*incises*) like “dit Rieux” or “dit-il” are found within quotes, which is much less confusing than your question implies.

Compare this with your example

> “I didn't want to go,” she said. “But the truth is I knew I would regret it if I didn't.” She paused, idly turning over the picture in her hand. “It was the right choice.”

In French, you could find “she said” within the quotation marks but I would also put “She paused, idly turning over the picture in her hand” on the outside.

At the same time, you will also encounter many other ways to use quotation marks, either out of sloppiness or for creative effect.

Comment: Comme tu le dis, ça ne répond pas à la question. Sur le fond, l'utilisation des guillemets comme tu le décris est majoritaire, mais il y a aussi des éditeurs respectés qui n'utilisent pas de guillemets, juste des tirets pour indiquer les dialogues.

Comment: @Gilles Ça ne répond pas totalement à la question mais ça remet sérieusement en cause ses présupposés et me semble donc utile.

Answer (score -3):

None of the above is surprising because I've been confused by this inconsistency of dialogue punctuation ever since I started reading French novels. Also it doesn't help the flow when you often have to stop and check the subject of third person possessive pronouns in dialogues, not always conclusively. I think this "fuzziness" must have developed integrally with certain traits of French culture and I don't think it's entirely separable from a way of perceiving the world. There seems to be an unstated convention that you only need to go so far to present exactly what you are trying to communicate as a clear package. It implies a greater onus on recipients of it to deal with what is put in front of them as they think best.

Comment: Is it really such a French cultural thing as you say ? Then why is there so much "fuzziness" in the english spelling compared to its pronunciation ?  It seems you're sliding into a classical dominant language speaker trait : considering your language as efficient, useful and the others ones as folklore or useless frivolity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).